# Can only install some R-Packages (Ubuntu 14.04 server)

Tags: 14.04, server, apt, package-management, r

I am trying to install the FastRWeb package for R on this Ubuntu server. I updated sources.list with:

```
deb http://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/
```

I have tried both:

```
sudo apt-get install r-cran-FastRWeb
```

and, from inside R as an administrator:

```
install.packages(FastRWeb)
```

Neither work, I get the following output:

> Reading packages list... Done
>
> Building dependency tree
>
> Reading state information... Done
>
> E: Unable to locate package r-cran-FastRWeb

However, I have been able to install some packages (eg: RServe installed fine). Help! Please!

Comment: I bet you RServe came from another repo. `apt-cache policy` will reveal the details. Also `apt-cache search` ought to help with finding the actual package name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following along the instructions at http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.

I added a the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/r.list` with the following contents:

```
deb http://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/
```

ran:

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys E084DAB9
gpg -a --export E084DAB9 | sudo apt-key add -
```

then:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

Finally running `R` as root (`sudo R`) I installed FastRWeb with `install.packages()` by picking it from the list.

Comment: you shouldn't run R as root -- you don't need to to install packages! if the site library is not writable, R will offer to create a personal library for packages in your home directory